# How do I copy data between tables PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, set, sql-update

I have two tables: account_company and document_invoice.
Table account_company has 2 columns: company_id and company_name.
Table document_invoice has the same columns: company_id and company_name.
Something happened and delete all data from column company name from document_invoice.

How can I write SQL query to copy data from account company table to document_invoice?
I have been using UPDATE and SET but I don't know exactly how.

```
UPDATE document_invoice
   SET company_name = (SELECT company_name FROM account_company)
 WHERE document_id.company_name=document_id.account
```

[image]

Comment: Slightly OT, consider *not carrying* the company name in the document invoice table, unless you think the company name might change and you want to capture the value of company name from the time of the invoice.  (Even then you might consider temporal management of the issue, but that might be over the top.)  Redundant storage of data makes it more expensive to update and introduces a risk that they might fall out of sync.  This is what joins are for.  Don't believe FUD about joins being expensive.

Comment: I aggree with kgrittn: If you already have the company_id in document_invoice, there is no need to keep a copy of the company_name in that table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
UPDATE document_invoice t1 
SET company_name = t2.company_name
FROM account_company t2 
WHERE t1.company_id = t2.company_id
```