# How to copy data from one table to another based on ids present in third table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have three tables like

**Table1**

It's a blank table that have same columns as Table2.

**Table2**

It contains the actual data that needs to be copied in Table1.

```
id   cola   colb   colc cold
1     hd     dj    dj    dh
2     hf     uy    ug    se
...
```

**Table3**

Before copying data from Table2 to Table1, first I need to verify that if the id is present in Table3 or not. In other words I just want to copy the rows from Table2 to Table1 whose id exist in Table3.

```
id   col1    col2
1     xy      zz
2     ys      sh
```

One more thing **Table2** & **Table3** contains half millions of rows, so query must be feasible.

Comment: You might check question I asked 3 years ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351998/how-do-i-copy-data-between-tables-postgresql

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: This is really basic stuff. Start with a beginners tutorial on MySQL.

Comment: @Nitish I've already tried all the below answered queries but these required a lot of time & resources. I'm looking for a feasible solution either in form of query or tool etc.

Comment: @user2350535: You need to mind your language here. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

some one make this as a duplicate question
however the answer is

```
insert into Table1 
select * from Table2 where Table1.id=Table2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 using subquery:

```
insert into Table1 
select * from Table2 where id in (select id from Table3)
```

Option 2 using INNER JOIN:

```
insert into Table1 
select * from Table2 INNER JOIN Table3 USING(id);
```

Comment: Updated the post by adding a new way using INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **<kbd>[EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)</kbd>**

**Query**

```
insert into Table1(id, cola, colb, colc, cold)
select id, cola, colb, colc, cold
from Table2 t
where exists(
    select * from Table3
    where id = t.id
);
```

**OR** with `JOIN`.

```
insert into id, cola, colb, colc, cold
select t1.id, t1.cola, t1.colb, t1.colc, t1.cold
from Table2 t1
join Table3 t2
on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 insert into Table1 
select * from Table2 where id in (select id from Table3)
```

Above query will work if Number of columns in table1 and table2 are same

Else

```
    insert into Table1 (column1,column2,.....)
select column1,column2...  from Table2 where id in (select id from Table3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join. It is faster.

```
insert into table1 (id, cola, colb, colc, cold)
select t2.id,t2.cola,t2.colb,t2.colc,t2.cold 
  from table2 t2 
left join 
       table3 t3 
  on t2.id=t3.id
where t3.id is null
```